# Mac Catalyst- how to setBccRecipients for an email?

Tags: macos, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mac-catalyst, bcc

In converting my email app to Mac Catalyst, I found that the setBccRecipients function of MFMailComposeViewController fails, with a message "'setToBccRecipients' not supported" however the call I am trying to use is "setBccRecipients", and the documentation says that that is supported in Mac Catalyst.

Any suggestions? or is this a Catalyst bug?

my code is (edited for length)

```
picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setBccRecipients:contacts];
```

which works fine in iOS, and also works correctly for Mac Catalyst if used in its To or Cc variants

Comment: Do you get any solution for the same? As I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid not. Please raise this as a bug with Apple both as a bug and as a tech support request. They need multiple reports to raise the priority of a bug before they tackle it.

It’s probably something as simple as a typo in their code, that would take minutes to fix, but it’s prevented release of my app for months.